# Large substitution from symbolic matrix to numerical values while keeping 4 unknowns into the new matrix

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, variable-assignment, symbolic-math

I have to solve the equality between 2 matrices 12x12 containing a lot of symbolic variables and with which I perform inversion of the matrix. There are  only one unknown called `SIGAM_O, and FISH_O_SYM(1,1), FISH_O_SYM(1,2) and FISH_O_SYM(2,2) (FISH_O_SYM(2,1) = FISH_O_SYM(1,2)`.

My system is solved fastly when I take for example 2 matrices 2x2, the inversion is pretty direct.

Now, with the case of 2 matrices 12x12, I need before actually to inverse a 31x31 matrix of symbolic variables (I marginalize after), since inversion takes a lot of time.

I would like to benefit from my GPU NVIDIA card to achieve this inversion faster but the GPU optimization is not supported currently for Symbolic arrays.

Below the script where you will find the line of inversion:

```
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM)
```

and the entire code:

```
clear;
clc;
format long;
% 2 Fisher Matrixes symbolic : FISH_GCsp_SYM, : 1 cosmo params + 1 bias spectro put for common
%                              FISH_XC_SYM : 1 cosmo params + 2 bias photo correlated
% GCsp Fisher : 7 param cosmo and 5 bias spectro which will be summed
FISH_GCsp_SYM = sym('sp_', [17,17], 'positive');
% Force symmetry for GCsp
FISH_GCsp_SYM = tril(FISH_GCsp_SYM.') + triu(FISH_GCsp_SYM,1)
% GCph Fisher : 7 param cosmo + 3 I.A + 11 bias photo correlated 
FISH_XC_SYM = sym('xc_', [21,21], 'positive');
% Force symmetry for GCph
FISH_XC_SYM = tril(FISH_XC_SYM.') + triu(FISH_XC_SYM,1)
% Brutal Common Bias : sum of 7 cosmo param ans 5 bias spectro : FISH_ALL1 = first left matrix
FISH_ALL1 = sym('xc_', [12,12], 'positive');
% Sum cosmo
FISH_ALL1(1:7,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,1:7) + FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,1:7);
% Brutal sum of bias
FISH_ALL1(7:12,7:12) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:12,7:12) + FISH_XC_SYM(15:20,15:20);
% Adding new observable "O" terms
FISH_O_SYM = sym('o_', [2,2], 'positive');
% Definition of sigma_o
SIGMA_O = sym('sigma_o', 'positive');
FISH_O_SYM = 1/(SIGMA_O*SIGMA_O) * FISH_O_SYM
% Force symmetry
FISH_O_SYM = (tril(FISH_O_SYM.') + triu(FISH_O_SYM,1))
FISH_O_SYM
%FISH_SYM = sym('xc_', [31,31], 'positive');
%FISH_BIG_GCsp = sym('sp_', [31,31], 'positive');
%FISH_BIG_XC = sym('xc_', [31,31], 'positive');
FISH_SYM = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_GCsp = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_XC = zeros(31,31,'sym');

% Block bias spectro + pshot and correlations;
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,1:7);

% Block bias photo and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,1:7);

% Block I.A and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,1:7);

% Final summation
FISH_SYM = FISH_BIG_GCsp + FISH_BIG_XC;

% Add O observable
FISH_SYM(6,6) = FISH_SYM(6,6) + FISH_O_SYM(1,1);
FISH_SYM(6,26) = FISH_SYM(6,26) + FISH_O_SYM(2,2);
FISH_SYM(26,6) = FISH_SYM(26,6) + FISH_O_SYM(1,2);
FISH_SYM(26,26) = FISH_SYM(26,26) + FISH_O_SYM(2,1);

% Force symmetry
FISH_SYM = (tril(FISH_SYM.') + triu(FISH_SYM,1))

% Marginalize FISH_SYM2 in order to get back a 2x2 matrix
% Invert to marginalyze : take a long long time 
COV_ALL = inv(FISH_SYM);
% Marginalize
COV_ALL([13:31],:) = [];
COV_ALL(:,[13:31]) = [];
FISH_ALL2 = inv(COV_ALL);
FISH_ALL1
FISH_ALL2
% Matricial equation to solve
eqn = FISH_ALL1 == FISH_ALL2;
% Solving : sigma_o unknown
[solx, parameters, conditions] = solve(eqn, SIGMA_O, 'ReturnConditions', true);
solx
```

Actually, this inversion of 31x31 size takes a long long time (I had to stop it).

**So, now, the strategy is to replace almost all the symbolic unknowns by numerical values: I want just to keep 4 unknown (`SIGAM_O, and FISH_O_SYM(1,1), FISH_O_SYM(1,2) and FISH_O_SYM(2,2) (FISH_O_SYM(2,1) = FISH_O_SYM(1,2)`)**

So, I would like to know how to do a large substitution of arrays `FISH_XC_SYM` and `FISH_GCsp_SYM` by numerical values of the equivalent of these 2 matrixes.

I can do for example:

```
FISG_GCsp_NUM = load('Fisher_GCsp_num.dat')
FISG_XC_NUM = load('Fisher_XC_num.dat')
```

But how to assign quickly to both arrays `FISH_GCsp_SYM` and `FISH_XC_SYM` the numerical values of arrays `FISH_GCsp_NUM` and `FISH_XC_NUM`, all of this while keeping the 4 unknown above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author in order to move it to the answer space)*.

I resolve this issue by doing simply:

```
FISH_GCsp_SYM = load('file1.dat);
FISH_XC_SYM = load('file2.dat'); 

FISH_SYM = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_GCsp = zeros(31,31,'sym');
FISH_BIG_XC = zeros(31,31,'sym');

% Block bias spectro + pshot and correlations;
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(1:7,7:17) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(1:7,7:17);
FISH_BIG_GCsp(7:17,1:7) = FISH_GCsp_SYM(7:17,1:7);

% Block bias photo and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,1:7);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,21:31) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,11:21);
FISH_BIG_XC(21:31,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(11:21,1:7);

% Block I.A and correlations;
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(1:7,18:20) = FISH_XC_SYM(1:7,8:10);
FISH_BIG_XC(18:20,1:7) = FISH_XC_SYM(8:10,1:7);
```

and everything is done!